# Is it possible to simplify this if statement?

Tags: blazor

Here's the code.  Is it possible to one-line this code?  I know of the (()?:) format, but not sure how to do this in Blazor.

```
<td>
  @if (piece.PublisherId == null)
  {
    @((MarkupString)$"<i>empty</i>")
  }
  else
  {
    @piece.Publisher.Name
  }
</td>
```

Comment: For good semantics, I recommend `@if (piece.PublisherId is null)` instead of `== null`.  Otherwise, see @Henk Holterman's answer.  As for one-lining: you CAN, if you're trying to compare Blazor to another framework that's bragging about what one line can do, but I think that makes your code less readable.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to simplify this if statement?

Sure.  Replace

```
@((MarkupString)$"<i>empty</i>")
```

with

```
<i>empty</i>"
```

> Is it possible to one-line this code?

Sure.

```
@if (piece.PublisherId == null) { <i>empty</i> } else { @piece.Publisher.Name }
```

But a Component might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Henk Holterman's answer:

Using the ?:;

```
@((MarkupString)(piece.PublisherId is null ? "<i>Empty</i>" : $"{piece.PublisherId}"))
```

Personally I like to keep my markup code as clean as possible so I would do something like this:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<div class="p2">
    DATA : @this.GetDataDiplay(null)
</div>

@code {
    private MarkupString GetDataDiplay(int? value) 
        => new MarkupString(value is null 
            ? "<i>Empty</i>" 
            : $"{value}");
}
```